# Assigning queue as an approver

Tags: approval-process

I have an requirement. I am having a custom object and a text field on this object to store a queue id. There can be many queues in the system. Now what I want is that whenever a particular record of this object is submitted for approval then associated queue must be set as the approver for this record.

How to achieve this? Any thoughts?